# Airpush classes could not be instantiated

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, airpush

[image: Eclipse Graphical Layout and my error]

I dowloaded the Airpush Bundle SDK 1.0 becuase I want to add banner ads to my app. I imported the sdk to my project, and I added rules to my manifest.

However, when I run my program I do not see any ads.

Every time in the layout manager it says "could not be instantiated" as seen in my screenshot above.

I tried to delete google play services, and reload it into project, but did not change anything.

Here's the text of the error message:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.bplxjxdpse.achmyqxdlf225456.AdView (Open Class, Show Error Log)
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code when shown in Eclipse
```

Answer (score 1):

Send this to their developers, they should be skipping a few things in their class and draw something for the developers to see if `editMode` is active, just like the error says. You can't do much unless you have access to the sources.

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
    if (isInEditMode()) {
        // This will be shown in XML layout design
        Paint mTitlePaint = new Paint();
        mTitlePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mTitlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mTitlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mTitlePaint.setTextSize(40);
        String mTitle = "Ad will appear here";
        float xPos = ((getMeasuredWidth() - mTitlePaint.measureText(mTitle)) / 2.0f);
        float yPos = (getMeasuredHeight() / 2.0f);
        float titleHeight = Math.abs(mTitlePaint.descent() + mTitlePaint.ascent());
        yPos += titleHeight / 2.0f;
        canvas.drawText(mTitle, xPos, yPos, mTitlePaint);
    }
}
```